# How to optionally exclude gem pg from the Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubygems

In our team some people do not have pg gem installed on their machines. At the moment we use two seprate database configs that are being copied to database.yml. We had problems with that approach because we had to keep commenting out gem pg in our Gemfile. So I tried following in our Gemfile:

```
unless ['host1, 'host2'].include? `hostname`.strip!
  gem 'pg'
end
```

It seemed to work, but the boss wants a better solution, so that he can test the app on his laptop without having to install Postgres and without having his hostname in the Gemfile.

```
Gem::Specification.all_names
```

doesn't show pg being installed although 'gem list pg --local' shows it is installed.

Trying to use `gem list pg --local` in the Gemfile doesn't work because the system seems to go into infinite loop if you don't have pg installed.

Is there something similar to 'Gem::Specification.all_names' that correctly shows list of installed gems that could be used in optional excluding of gems in a Gemfile. Or is there a better way to use gifferent Gems on different machines for the above mentioned scenario?

### note

```
if File.open('./config/database.yml').read.each_line.first.index('Postgre').is_a?(Integer)
 gem 'pg'
end
```

seems to work but now I get this when I run bundle install:

```
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the group postgres were not installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

any idea where it comes form?

### note 2

'Gems in the group postgres were not installed' was fixed after running: rm -r ./.bundle

Comment: Bosses are a pain :). You could use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) and add a `MYAPP_DB_DRIVER` environmental variable.

Comment: Sorry just realised a var set with dotenv would not be available when the gem file is read, you should set it manually instead.

Comment: I'm not bothered about selecting the database driver. This is done copying correct database.yml. I want to avoid errors releated to missing pg gem.

Comment: You can call the variable whatever you want, my point was that you would test for `ENV["USE_POSTGRESS"]` or whatever in your gemfile instead of using the hostname.

Comment: you can specify the gem in a particular 'group'. For example if you have production specific gems to be installed on a machine then add the gem under `group :production do gem 'pg' end`.
[Example of a Gemfile](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/master/Gemfile)

Comment: @swap.nil doesn´t cover the case where developers want to be able to test/develop on pg and also sqlite.

Comment: '$ cp ./config/database.yml.sqlite.example ./config/database.yml' seems to fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solutions would be to use a [custom environment](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3535-beyond-the-default-rails-environments) and bundler group.

You might have noticed this line in `config/application.rb`:

```
# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

Which means running `rails s -e bossmode` would require the gems in:

```
group :bossmode do
  # no pg in here...
end
```

An even better solution would be to convince your boss to [*KISS*](http://www.internetslang.com/KISS-meaning-definition.asp) and use PG. The performance cost even on a lowly macbook air is tiny.

Comment: Additional reading: [Yehuda Katz: The How and Why of Bundler Groups](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/09/the-how-and-why-of-bundler-groups/)